# Prometheus exporter client keeps sending the last value after the source stops

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I wrote an exporter to export some data such as CPU and memory usage of different processes in my application using the Prometheus client. Everything is working then I noticed that when I kill a process the client continues to send the last value it received as long as the exporter is up.

I used gaugevec and the `Set` method. I suspect that because of `Set` the client has been set to that value and since it is not receiving any new value it just keeps sending the last one. Below is my code:

```golang
var CpuPercentValue = prometheus.NewGaugeVec(
    prometheus.GaugeOpts{
        Namespace: "MyExporter",
        Name:      "CpuPercentValue",
        Help:      "CpuPercentValue",
    },
    []string{
        "namespace",
        "proc_qID",
        "opID",
    },
)

var MemoryValue = prometheus.NewGaugeVec(
    prometheus.GaugeOpts{
        Namespace: "MyExporter",
        Name:      "MemoryValue",
        Help:      "MemoryValue",
    },
    []string{
        "namespace",
        "proc_qID",
        "opID",
    },
)

var RunThreadsValue = prometheus.NewGaugeVec(
    prometheus.GaugeOpts{
        Namespace: "MyExporter",
        Name:      "RunThreadsValue",
        Help:      "RunThreadsValue",
    },
    []string{
        "namespace",
        "proc_qID",
        "opID",
    },
)

prometheus.MustRegister(CpuPercentValue)
prometheus.MustRegister(MemoryValue)
prometheus.MustRegister(RunThreadsValue)

go func() {
    for d := range msgs {
        // I get the labels from the RabbitMQ routingkey
        routingkey = strings.Split(d.RoutingKey, ".")
        procid = routingkey[0]
        opid = routingkey[1]

        // get the data
        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(d.Body), opst)
        failOnError(err, "failed to Unmarshal the opstat")

        // set the values
        // namespace here is the different namespaces in a Kubernetes cluster
        CpuPercentValue.With(prometheus.Labels{"namespace": namespace, "proc_qID": procid, "opID": opid}).Set(opst.CpuPercent.Value)
        MemoryValue.With(prometheus.Labels{"namespace": namespace, "proc_qID": procid, "opID": opid}).Set(opst.Memory.Value)
        RunThreadsValue.With(prometheus.Labels{"namespace": namespace, "proc_qID": procid, "opID": opid}).Set(opst.NumThreads.Value)
    }
}()
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was not deleting the labels that were not publishing. I expected that the Prometheus client just exports when it receives a new value but that assumption/expectation was wrong.